# Local Server Creation On MAC

Tags: java, networking, server, network-programming, client-server

So basically I have a Java game that works with, 1 server, and two clients connecting to it. I’m currently using the local host address to test and a random port, however I would like to transition it to a local address. Basically I want other computers both Mac and pc to be able to connect to a non-internet enabled network on my Mac, where I can then have a port already port forward for the game to connect. I’ve done this with an actual router, but I’m unsure how I would do it here, would I use Apache or some other option

Comment: What is the network connection you are trying to achieve? I imagine you would use the router at your home. Or are you going to use a separate switch? Another option is 1 to 1 connection between 2 computers.

Comment: I am trying to achieve an effect similar to a router, but without the WiFi connectivity, and with a computer acting as the router instead. I want to make a network on my computer for others to connect too, so even without internet I can allow the client and server to connect to each other

Comment: Yes, but I was asking how the other 2 computers will be connected to your server. Depending on that, you simply need to configure network parameters for all 3 computers and it should work as it works on a local address.

Comment: @N.U.Ekici so they’d be connected by creating a new socket on each of them to the ip of my Mac after they have been connected in a local network

Comment: If your machines can ping the server, connecting with the IP of the server should work. I would suggest turning the server's firewall off if there is an issue with pinging or otherwise connecting with your code.

Comment: @N.U.Ekici thanks that helps and I’m familiar with using java sockets to do so, but I’m wondering what I would do to make the server on said Mac computer, cause otherwise I wouldn’t have an IP to ping